# convert cURL command line into python script

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to convert these sequence of CURL commands into python script. Can someone assist me on this please? There should be function/method for command 3 and 4 below which will accept the parameter as "data" to pass to command 3 below and note to process as query argument in command 4 below(eg. of node in command 4 below: cid=29-0&pid=12&gid=29-0&type=1")

```
curl --cookie-jar /mydir/cookies.tmp -o dev/null "http://xyz:8080/main/main.faces"

curl --cookie /mydir/cookies.tmp  --location --cookie-jar /mydir/cookies.tmp --data "j_username=test@domain.com&j_password=test" -o /dev/null "http://xyz.com:8080/main/j_sec_check"

curl --cookie /mydir/cookies.tmp --data "cmd=u&rid=5&cid=29-0&pid=12&gid=29-0&type=1&blablblablablablablablblablablablablablblablablablablablblablablabla" "http://xyz.com:8080/main/rest/testrestXML"

curl --cookie /mydir/cookies.tmp "http://xyz.com:8080/main/rest/process?cid=29-0&pid=12&gid=29-0&type=1"
```

Comment: I usually do, but if I have missed any then I'm sorry. I will make sure moving forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without doing it all for you, start with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). The relevant function is `urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com")`. If you pass a second parameter, it is treated as the data in a POST request. To do a GET request, just add url encoded parameters to the URL. urllib (without the `2`) has a urlencode function if you need it.

If you need to use cookies, use cookielib. The [examples](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#examples) for it show you how.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your tip. It helped to increase my knowledge base. What I did was constructed cmd and used  os.system(cmd) to achieve that task and wrapped in python function.

Comment: @doneright: You're welcome. Calling system commands isn't ideal (not very portable, etc.), but if it only needs to work on one computer, fair enough.